# Deleting old rows when a new one is added and there are more than 100 rows

Tags: mysql, trigger

For a school assignment we need to keep the number of rows in a MySQL table under 100. The newest rows must stay. I've tried using a trigger but with no success.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_rows 
AFTER INSERT ON `check`.log 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `check`.log)>100 
   THEN 
      DELETE FROM `check`.log LIMIT 1; 
   END IF; 
END
```

This resulted in the following error:

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'log' in stored function/trigger
> because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
> function/trigger.

Then I tried monitoring `/var/lib/mysql/check/log.ibd` with `incron` and let it execute a script. When I open `log.ibd` with nano, `incron` executes my script, but when I use MySQL to insert something into it, nothing happens.

The incron instruction:

```
/var/lib/mysql/check/log.ibd IN_ALL_EVENTS /etc/scripts/test
```

How can I ensure that the table never has more than 100 rows?

Comment: Read error message carefully! It tells you **CANNOT** delete from the table which event the trigger is defined on. So trigger cannot help you - SP only, either insert-delete or rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is not specifying which row to delete and is only limiting it to deleting a single record. You are going to want to update the trigger to specify which record to delete and I would guess that you want to delete the oldest one.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html

> The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be deleted

Answer (score 0):

[Can triggers access tables?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-trigger-procedure)

> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
> can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a
> table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
> statement that invoked the function or trigger.

---

> How can I ensure that the table never has more than 100 rows?

You can use the following routines to maintain the 100 rows (inserts the latest row and deletes the older one once the row count is 100) in the table `t1`.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  c1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Create a trigger which limits the number of rows to 100.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trigr_t1 BEFORE INSERT ON t1
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_db`.t1) = 100 
      THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error has occurred - table t1 row count has reached 100. Use the procedure insert_t1 to insert a row.';
      END IF;
    END//
delimiter ;
```

Create a procedure which maintains 100 rows while inserting new row (and deleting the older row).

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_t1()
  BEGIN
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_db`.t1) < 100 
   THEN 
      INSERT INTO `test_db`.t1 VALUES();
   ELSEIF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_db`.t1) = 100
   THEN
      DELETE FROM `test_db`.t1 LIMIT 1;
      INSERT INTO `test_db`.t1 VALUES();
   ELSE
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error has occurred - table row count is already > 100 !!!';
   END IF; 
  END//
delimiter ;
```

Now, you can insert rows into the table `t1`, initially:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES();
```

Or, use the:

```
CALL insert_t1();
```

Once, the row count is 100, the trigger `trigr_t1` will not allow any inserts using the `INSERT INTO ...` syntax. Then, you can use the procedure to insert new rows:

```
CALL insert_t1();
```